# How to decide what to do with missing data when doing data analysis?

Tags: matlab, missing-data

I'm doing data analysis with MATLAB and I have a bunch of files with missing data here and there and somewhere even whole days or months worth of data is missing, because sensor devices have been fixed or changed or something like that.

My question is: How to decide what to do with missing data? When is it best to set missing data just equal to zero and when to use interpolation or something like that?

My professor advised me just to set the missing values equal zero, should I proceed this way?

*edit*: My data consists of weather data: nitrogen oxyde, nitrogen dioxide, temperature, wind, amount of rain etc.. My task is to forecast upcoming changes in the weather conditions. Here is a sample of my data values (`-99` means error value)

```
5 3 0 6 2 0 0 -99 17 24 94 74 -99 -99 -99 -99 10 5 3 5 5 17 1 3 3 0 6 2 0 0 0 -99
13 25 50 35 19 8 7 3 3 4 4 6 6 7 2 3 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 -99 5 7 28 27 16 9 7 7 7 9 9 11 
6 12
```

This is just a small sample, I have lots of this data

Comment: What kind of model are you trying to fit? It appears you may be trying to do some kind of standard time series analysis. If that is the case, you should still be able to write down and optimize the likelihood for the observed data, ignoring the missing data, which would still give you a basis for prediction of future values. I'm not aware of any software that does this (although I'm sure there's an `R` package, somewhere) so you may have to "write-your-own". I certainly agree with Peter Flom's statement that calling the missing values a numerical value like `0` is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Hello, I'm very new in time series, but yes I'm trying to make an AR-model from the data and my goal is to forecast the NO, NO2-quantities for the future =) Hope this clarifies a bit, thank you for your answer! =) I'm using MATLAB to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting missing data = 0 cannot be right, unless there is something very unusual about your situation that you are not telling us.

The right thing to do depends on 
1) Why the data are missing. Are they missing completely at random, missing at random, or not missing at random?
2) How much data are missing. 
3) What analysis you plan to do.

MCAR means that the data are missing for reasons completely unrelated to the data themselves. MAR means that the reasons the data are missing are captured by data that you have.
NMAR means neither of the above is true. In this situation, you have a complex problem.

If very little data are missing, you can use case deletion or mean substitution.
If more data are missing and they are MCAR or MAR, one good method is multiple imputation.

Comment: Good answer to missing data in general, but I am not uncertain whether it adequately adresses the more specific concerns here . We are looking at time series and want to predict makes deletion unfeasible and even multiple imputation problematic if entire months are missing (which means some seasonal effects have been lost).

Answer (score 4):

Just a short recipe to get you started. Replace -99 by a proper NA code, find out how your intended analysis method handles the missing data, see what Little and Rubin (2002) write about this method, and then evaluate whether the method is sensible for your data.

Comment: Sounds like a good starting point.  Would be most helpful if you could track down a freely available source for that article and share a link.

Comment: It's a book, so you will have to buy or lend it. It is definitely worth the investment if you are serious about missing data.